# Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: python, requests

На сайте используется сертификат, но при запросе он мне не нужен, выключаю его и получаю такую ошибку, хотя и с включенным сертификатом та же беда

Сталкивался кто?

```
import json
import time
import requests
import urllib3

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

urllib3.disable_warnings()


def main():
    url = "<url>"
    params = {"token": "<token>",
              "dbId": "<id>",
              "method": "query",
              "args": {"path": "<path>",
                       "params": {"AuthUserID": "<userId>",
                                  "d1": "date1",
                                  "d2": "date2",
                                  "filter": "",
                                  "status": 0,
                                  "id": "",
                                  "top": 2
                                  }
                       },
              }
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=1)
    session = requests.Session()
    session.cert = ('Click.pem', 'click.key')
    session.mount(url, adapter)
    try:
        r = session.post(url=url, data=params, verify=False)
        print('STATUS CODE:', r.status_code)
        print(r.text)
    except ConnectionError as ce:
        print(ce)
```

Ошибка:

```
   STATUS CODE: 500
   error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Comment: У Вас не валидный json. Так как после `"args"` идет `},`. Уберите запятую!

Comment: @DmitriiSedov не особо помогло - ошибка та же

Comment: Покажите json, прилетающий в целевой url с post'ом...

Answer (score 0):

Измени `data=params` на `json=params`. Либо сделай дамп и пошли данные текстом, а-ля `data=json.dumps(params)`, тут в зависимости от того, что делается на стороне сервера. `json=params` пропишет в запросе тип контента `application/json`, `data=params` же пропишет `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - сервер же, видимо, ждет JSON и не проверяет тип контента вообще (хотя могу здесь и ошибаться).